# Interstitial close shows previous screen for 1 - 2 seconds before navigating to the second screen (Android)

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have an app that has two activities (Main Activity and Learning Activity). The first activity contains a button. Clicking on it will navigate user to another screen. Before navigating to another screen the interstitial ad shows up. The problem is when I close the Interstitial Main Activity shows up for 1 - 2 seconds before navigating to Learning Activity. How to fix it?

Here is my Main Activity class:

```
​​public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  AdsManager adsManager;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       loadAds();
    }

  void loadAds() {
    adsManager = new AdsManager(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
   switch (view.getId()) {
     case R.id.learnButton:
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, LearningActivity.class);
       if (adsManager != null) {
         adsManager.showAd(intent);
       } else {
         startActivity(intent);
       }
       break;
}
```

Here is my AdsManager class:

```
class AdsManager {
  private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
  private Context context;

  AdsManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    MobileAds.initialize(context, context.getString(R.string.adMobAppId));
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(context.getString(R.string.adMobUnitId));
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder()
      .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
      .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(builder.build());
  }

  void showAd(Intent intent) {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAdClosed() {
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }
      });
    }
    else {
      context.startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}​
```

Comment: this is happening because you are loading ad before loading the next page and its disallowed interstitial implementation policy. Refer to this link https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Comment: I am loading ad before loading next page because if ad would not be loaded before user click a button there would be a delay in showing ad adter user navigates to the second screen which would cause an unexpected ad showing when user is already on the second screen. This would be a policy violation.